# Continue to use the same connection after receiving [FIN, ACK]

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I see that some servers will stop the connection once a single request is done by sending [FIN, ACK]

From wiki,

> A connection can be "half-open", in which case one side has terminated its end, but the other has not. The side that has terminated can no longer send any data into the connection, but the other side can. The terminating side should continue reading the data until the other side terminates as well.

In case I want to speed up the requests by avoiding repeating handshake per request. Is it possible for the client to keep communicating even the server terminated its end? Will there be any response from the server or the server just read my request without responding?

Comment: Usual rubbish from Wikipedia. You can ignore the final sentence unless your application protocol demands otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you terminate your *write* half of TCP connection, it means that you're done with communicating and you just wait for your partner (whether it's a server, client or equal counterpart) to finish with it's transmissions. When your partner is ready, he terminates his *write* half and TCP connection is then closed.

So if a server has terminated its end, you're still able to send data reliably, but aren't able to receive any result.

If you don't want any handshakes in your TCP, why not taking a protocol without handshakes? For example UDP, especially if the messages aren't heavy and intense.

Comment: If I can still send the data without any response, will the server process what I had sent?

Comment: I cannot control the protocol. I want to try to speed things up in TCP connection when the server close connection per request

Comment: @IsoletChan it depends on a server. It can continue reading until you don't close a connection on your side. It can destroy the related socket structures right after closing its write side. It can continue reading but will destroy connection when it realizes it can't answer you. Totally depends on the implementation. Just try.